# Show iPhone connection speed

Tags: iphone, performance, cellular-data

I'd like to know if there is a way to show the current mobile link speed on my iPhone 5s. I mean the "physical" max. of the currently negotiated connection to the cell tower, not the actual throughput, I know there are tons of apps to measure those.

Is there a way?

Comment: The iOS does not have this capability.

Comment: We used to use field test mode to get that sort of information when GSM/3G networks were common. I don't know if LTE has any such data exposed to the user on iOS in a form that we can use. Would you be OK with a jailbrak solution? clearly the radio has all this information and I believe much of it is logged to Diagnostics & Usage but that isn't easily consumed or presented to us as end users.

Comment: I wasn't planning to jailbreak my phone. I'm surprised theres no way to get that information, but I'm not an app developer, so what do I know. Do you happen to know if its different for android?

Comment: This is the field test dial code for the iPhone: \*3001#12345#\*

It doesn't show things like up-/download rate, so I guess the baseband doesn't forward that information to iOS.